# Why does readcsv("universe.csv") result in an error but readcsv(f) works fine

Tags: windows, csv, file-io, julia

I came across an awkward error when using readcsv. When I read a csv file from my OneDrive in Julia using `readcsv("universe.csv")` I get an error, but when I open the file first and use the stream with readcsv it works fine.

```
symbols = readcsv("universe.csv")
```

results in stat: invalid argument (EINVAL) error

but

```
f1 = open("universe.csv", "r")
symbols = readcsv(f1)
close(f1)
```

works fine

Why does `readcsv("universe.csv")` result in an error but `readcsv(f)` work fine?

Comment: It's probably [this known issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/24483) caused by new Windows placeholders in the last creators update. I'm guessing it'll get fixed after stable v0.7 but before v1.0. In the meantime, just use the work-around (as you've shown in the question).